# Messenger bot: You cannot access the app till you log in to www.facebook.com and follow the instructions given. No instructions were given

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger-bot

My messenger bot that was running for two months but this night something changed and for unclear reasons, I can't POST back to Facebook which returns an error as a response.


From begging:

- This is the communication scheme

```
# VS - alias for the Server running chatbot

# this is what should happen
1. User -> message  -> FB   # User sends a message via messenger
2. VS   <- message  <- FB   # Facebook does its thing and send me REST API POST request 
3. VS   -> response -> FB   # I send the response meant for the User
4. User <- response <- FB   # Facebook forwards the response to User 

# this is what is happening
1. User -> message  -> FB  # works
2. VS   <- message  <- FB  # works
3. VS   -> response -> FB  # works
4. VS   <- error    <- FB  # FB returns an 400 error and User gets no response
```

- This is the error returned in the fourth step.

```
# The error response from step 4
'{"error":{
    "message":"You cannot access the app till you log in to www.facebook.com and follow the 
               instructions given.",  ### !! above !! ###
    "type":"OAuthException",
    "code":190,
    "error_data": "{\"checkpoint_url\" : \"https:\\\/\\\/www.facebook.com\"}",
    "error_subcode":459,
    "fbtrace_id":"A9MjzGGqQfKY2vPsszXQemu"
    }
}'
```

I did as said in the message field but there were no instructions on `facebook.com` nor the `developers.facebook.com`. I checked from the correct account.

I did change a thing in server code, but it was a simple bug fix that shouldn't have had an impact on communication with Facebook. Obviously, I have tested it and everything worked fine. 
But overnight FB decided that everything was not fine and started returning errors to every `response` sent (`response` is the third step in the communication scheme). 


Do you know what this error is about or maybe where can I find help because Facebook doesn't provide real support?

Comment: This sounds like some kind of consent/agreement to specific terms or something is missing. Have you checked your app dashboard, to see if there’s anything like that in there somewhere?

Comment: Yes, I did but unfortunately, nothing was there. On the other hand, I did manage to finally fix this it is not very technical but I will write an answer because I might help someone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Quick fix:

- Log in to every administrator account of the app and check notifications or
  possible security issues. 
   For me it was changing the password of an account
  that I don't use daily.
- Generate new Access Token in `App Dashboard/Messenger/Settings` and reconfigure
  your server to use it.

#### Longer version

The app has two administrator accounts, one is my usual and the other one was created specifically for this project (what was unnecessary). 

Looking from my main account, I couldn't find anything that would tell me what is wrong, when writing this question, just to be sure I checked the other one. FB prompted me to change my password for security reasons because someone tried to log in from the USA (but I haven't tried to log in to this account lately). 

I changed the password and looked for notifications that would tell me what was wrong. Nothing. Error response didn't change either in logs.

Today with nothing better in mind I switched from: `requests.post("https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages")`

to:
`requests.post("https://graph.facebook.com/v6.0/me/messages")` 
and checked logs, where I found this response:

```
"error":{
    "message":"Error validating access token: The session has been invalidated 
               because the user changed their password or Facebook has changed the 
               session for security reasons.",
    "type":"OAuthException",
    "code":190,
    "error_subcode":460,
    "fbtrace_id":"Ay7KPJ9_gtv5s3ebKjm5LG_"
}}'
```

Now I did exactly what it said and generated a new Access Token in
`App Dashboard/Messenger/Setting` and reconfigured my server. This was it.
Then from curiosity, I changed back the `v6.0` to `v2.6` and everything still worked fine.